# Partially blurring UIImage in objective C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I know how to blur a whole image, but I just want to blur a part of the image like the face. Answers are appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I don't have any good ideas so far so I haven't tried any. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: You could crop out the part you want blurred, blur it, and draw it back over the original image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to close this thread, I used both @Anshu's and @Michael's suggestions. Here are my steps:

1. Crop the part the image that needs blurred.
2. Use [UIImage+Stack](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS/blob/master/Classes/UIImage+StackBlur.m) to blur the cropped image.
3. Place the blurred image on top of the original image.
4. Combine the two images together to one new image.

Answer (score 3):

This should get you started: https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS ?

You could look inside the [UIImage+Stack](https://github.com/tomsoft1/StackBluriOS/blob/master/Classes/UIImage+StackBlur.m) implementation and use what you find there to make a version of this method that blurs a specific section of your image.

Something like:

```
- (UIImage*) stackBlur:(NSUInteger)inradius insideRect:(NSRect)rect;
```

Hint: the code from line #166 is where the blur class starts looping over the image pixels and blurring them.

Comment: Thanks. But this one still blurs the whole image. Any hints on how to blur only parts of the image?

Comment: That's exactly what I was thinking about. I'll give it a try.

Comment: @Wenbo let us know how you get on ;)

Comment: Well it's not easy to deal with the pixels. I tried to change the x,y ranges in the loops but it didn't seem to work. I used @Anshu's suggestion to do the partial blurring.

Comment: @Wenbo I hadn't seen his suggestion, glad to hear that you found a solution!