# How to merge 3 images in to one and create a blur effect at the junction of each image in iOS?

Tags: image, ios6, merge, core-image, imagefilter

I want to merge 3 images in to one and at the junction of each image, i want to create a **blur effect** like the one in this pic.

[image]

I've already done the merge of three images by using this code,

[pastie.org/8180134](http://pastie.org/8180134)

So, now i want to create the blur effect alone at their junction. I tried creating a blur effect by using ***GPUImage*** framework and **core Image filters**, but the filter effect gets applied for the whole image and not for the above mentioned (in image) specific area. So, how can i do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14107979/blur-an-image-of-specific-part-rectangular-circular/14108694#14108694

Answer (score 0):

Try blurring the image in another layer and use a mask to selectively a portion of one over the other.